# Android null object reference on ProgressBar in dialog

Tags: android, nullreferenceexception, android-progressbar

I have the following code where I create a ProgressBar in a dialog:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.wait_for_response_dialog);

final ProgressBar bar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.responseWaitBar);
final int[] i = {0};

bar.setProgress(i[0]);
```

And my layout of the ProressBar is the following in `wait_for_response_dialog.xml`:

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/responseWaitBar"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

But I get the following error for line `bar.setProgress(i[0]);`:

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ProgressBar.setProgress(int)' on a null object reference`

Comment: man accept answer if helped. I answered first.

Comment: I am sorry, but stackoverflow said that Gustavo was one minute earlier than you...

Comment: It says I was 2 mins earlier to him.

Comment: Where can I see this information? Right now, it only shows "16 hours" on both answers...

Comment: point the cursor on `16 hours ago` and a popup will come after 1 sec and then see the exact time.

Comment: Ok, my bad. I change the correct answer then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dialog` to init. the `ProgressBar`.

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.wait_for_response_dialog);

final ProgressBar bar = (ProgressBar)dialog.findViewById(R.id.responseWaitBar);
final int[] i = {0};

bar.setProgress(i[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If your ProgressBar is inside your dialog you need to change the line

```
final ProgressBar bar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.responseWaitBar);
```

for this

```
final ProgressBar bar = (ProgressBar) dialog.findViewById(R.id.responseWaitBar);
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Avoid view Binding,it was the reason for application crash.

```html
 ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading....");
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.show();
```

use this for Showing progress bar

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).